# ODE involving two functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

If I have the following two ODEs:
$$f'(x)g(x)=f''(x)g(x)+f'(x)g'(x)$$
$$f(x)g'(x)=f(x)g''(x)+f'(x)g'(x)$$
With the initial conditions of:
$\begin{cases}f(0)=g(0)=1
\\
f'(0)=a>0
\\
g'(0)=b>0
\end{cases}$

Is it possible to solve for $f$ and $g$ or do we need more information?

Comment: Can you fix any typos, please?

Comment: I fixed them. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first equation, you can make the substitution $h(x)=f'(x)g(x),$ at which point it simplifies down to $h'(x)=h(x),$ with solution $h(x)=A e^{x}.$ Next, you can make the substitution $z(x)=f(x)g'(x),$ at which point the second equation becomes $z'(x)=z(x),$ with solution $z(x)=B e^x.$ So, we have
\begin{align*}
f'(x)g(x)&=Ae^x\\
f(x)g'(x)&=Be^x.
\end{align*}
It follows that $f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)=(A+B)e^x,$ or $(f(x)g(x))'=(A+B)e^x.$ Then
$$f(x)g(x)=(A+B)e^x+C $$
follows. The initial conditions imply $1=A+B+C,$ and
\begin{align*}
a\cdot 1&=A\\
b\cdot 1&=B.
\end{align*}
So, we must have $1=a+b+C,$ and
$$f(x)g(x)=(a+b)e^x+1-a-b. $$
This appears to be as far as you can go without more information.

Comment: Thank you. I will look for more information to get separability.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the two equations, you will get
$$f'g + fg' = f''g+2f'g'+fg''$$
$$\implies (fg)' = (fg)'' \implies f(x)g(x) = C_1e^x + C_2$$
But even with the initial conditions, I don't see a way to factor this into functions with those properties uniquely.

Comment: Thank you Ninad Munshi.